# How to switch off map markers clustering?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

any idea how to turn off this clustering feature?

```
// enable/disable the clustering feature
  self.enable = function (value) {
    if (enabled !== value) {
      enabled = value;
      redraw();
    }
  };
```

Sorry, just learning  o.o

Comment: if `self.enable` is boolean/logical value, and clustering is dependent from `value` which is probably `true`, so changing all code to `self.enable = false;` should solve your problem... probably :)

Comment: I thought so but not, it's not working, unfortunately